# use nodejs as web server in Cpanel that has apache as webserver

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, cpanel

I want to deploy my **Nodejs** app on a **cPanel** sharing hosting And I'm confused if I can use **Nodejs** as my default webserver or Or I must use Apache ?
And my second question is whether I should use Apache as a proxy web server?
And how do I handle in-app routing?

Comment: https://ittone.ma/ittone/node-js-how-to-run-nodejs-express-api-in-pm2-on-cpanel-shared-hosting-server/

Comment: thank you but not my problem answer

Comment: It will depend on weather that cPanel has nodejs support. This is not a cPanel problem but a hosting provider problem. CPanel itself is a very capable software for managing servers. However, what cPanel can or is allowed to do depends on how the provider configured it. There are lots of 3rd party modules/extensions that add features to cPanel and this includes node.js support. You need to ask you provider if they support node.js before paying them money

Comment: @slebetman thank you for your useful answer ، 
so you say that if my hosting provider gives me access I can use Nodejs itself as a web server instead of using the default C-Panel web server, but otherwise I have to use the hosting provider's default web server as a proxy?

Comment: You may not even be able to run node behind a proxy. Most cPanel hosting don't give you access to a command line/terminal. Only file/ftp access - which is usually enough for PHP or CGI hosting

Comment: @slebetman I shared this with my hosting provider and they said that my service can run Nodejs but I have to use LightSpeed web server . And if I want to use Node itself as a web server, I have to use VPS and not shared hosting so that I can disable the default web server and publish Node as the default web server.